# Empty FullText property with Tweetmode.Extended [update May 30th]

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm programming a .Net Core (2.1 preview, C# 7.3) Streaming Console App with L2T (5.0.0 beta 2) but even with the `strm.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended` the query gives "compat" tweets back, the FullText property is empty.

You can reproduce this with the L2T query below.

I searched online, I've found something similar (with 'search' instead of 'Streaming') but no answers, except to add `&& strm.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended`, which I did.

Any ideas?

```
        try
        {
            await
                (from strm in twitterCtx.Streaming
                        .WithCancellation(cancelTokenSrc.Token)
                 where
                    strm.Type == StreamingType.Filter
                    && strm.Track == "twitter"
                    && strm.Language == "nl"
                    && strm.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended
                 select strm)
                .StartAsync(async strm =>
                {
                    await HandleStreamResponse(strm);
                    if (count++ >= 20)
                        cancelTokenSrc.Cancel();
                });
        }
```

[**Update May 30th**]

Found something. It's in the subroutine "HandleStreamResponse" (code below). The `Status.TweetMode` *and* `Status.ExtendedTweet.TweetMode` both return "Compat" for all tweets, but the full text of a tweet is in `status.ExtendedTweet.FullText`

But even with this check, retweets are truncated to 140 chars max. I do not need retweets for my progam so I filter them out.

I do not know, yet, how to filter retweets from a stream directly (*is it possible?*), so I check the retweetstatus of the Status from the stream result. It's in the code below.

FYI: In the examples of Linq To Twitter for this subroutine Joe Mayo uses the following line of code, but that doesn't work: `Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", status.StatusID, status.User.ScreenNameResponse, status.Text ?? status.FullText);`

Even with `&& strm.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended` in the L2T query, the `status.FullText` is empty.

There is more code than neccesary in the example below, but I used it for clarity.

```
static async Task<int> HandleStreamResponse(StreamContent strm)
    {
        switch (strm.EntityType)
        {
            case StreamEntityType.Status:
                var status = strm.Entity as Status;

                if (status.RetweetedStatus.StatusID == 0)
                {
                    if (status.ExtendedTweet.FullText != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Longer than 140 - \"@{0}\": {1} (TweetMode:{2})", 
                            status.User.ScreenNameResponse, status.ExtendedTweet.FullText, status.TweetMode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Shorter than 140 - \"@{0}\": {1} (TweetMode:{2})", 
                            status.User.ScreenNameResponse, status.Text, status.TweetMode);
                    }
                }

                // Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", status.StatusID, status.User.ScreenNameResponse,  status.Text ?? status.FullText);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown - " + strm.Content + "\n");
                break;
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations:

1. `status.ExtentendedTweet.FullText` should hold the tweet in normal circumstances.
2. However, if the tweet is retweeted, then `status.RetweetedStatus.ExtendedTweet.FullText` should hold the tweet.
3. If you can't find the `FullText` in either of those circumstances, use `status.Text`.

I'm updating the sample with the following:

```
    case StreamEntityType.Status:
        var status = strm.Entity as Status;
        string text = null;
        if (status.ExtendedTweet?.FullText != null)
            text = status.ExtendedTweet?.FullText;
        else if (status.RetweetedStatus?.ExtendedTweet?.FullText != null)
            text = status.RetweetedStatus?.ExtendedTweet?.FullText;
        else
            text = status.Text;

        Console.WriteLine("Status - @{0}: {1}", status.User.ScreenNameResponse, text);
        break;
```

Note: Via [Twitter documentation (see Standard Streams)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates), `TweetMode` doesn't apply to streams. Additionally, the docs say the `ExtentedTweet` should always be there with `FullText`. As we can see, that isn't the full picture in practice. I'll mark `Streaming.TweetMode` as obsolete in upcoming releases.

Comment: Thank you Joe, this answers my question completely. I love using LinqToTwitter. I'm really thankful you provide extensive documentation, lots of samples and answering questions on Twitter and StackOverflow.